# PHP/ MySQL issue

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce, cs-cart

I have over 10,000 products so I won't be able to create a new web page for each one or add each one to my CMS individually.

Here's what I have:

- A CMS that allows me to mass-upload using a CSV file
- A cPanel GoDaddy Server with MySQL databases

Correct me if I'm wrong but is this the process for adding a product:

1. Connect the CMS to the cPanel server
2. Add products to the CMS using a CSV file
3. Create a database in MySQL ont he GoDaddy server.
4. Add PHP to website oriduct page to extract product information.

I'm confused as to how the product information is transferred from the CMS to the database in MySQL

Comment: im confused to, what CMS are you using ?

Comment: its installed and working? it has a csv import option?

Comment: It is yes. But is what I said correct, is that the way it works? :S

Comment: 1 makes no sense 2, ok yes. 3 no the CMS has already done that when you instlled it 4, no the CMS does that

Comment: 1. I need to download files from the CMs and install them into the GoDaddy cPanel server is wha tI was told to do.    4. I need to use PHP in the website for the website to interact with the server so it can extract all the product information and display it

Comment: you say its installed and working above, all you should need to do is the import.

Comment: But I need to do something like this to connect the product page with the database of products so they can be displayed: [link](https://www.developphp.com/video/PHP/Product-Display-Page)

Comment: no. that's the job of the CMS you installed - you should never have to write a line of code- that's why you installed this

Comment: since the CMS is installed onto the server, it doesn't make much sense to me that I don't need to use PHP to get the product information since it is the server I need to access. Just to clarify the CMS and the web hosting server are not the same company

Comment: CMS = content management system, it is managing the content so you don't have to write code. thats the point of installing it.

Comment: @Grant9196 Then you should update/clarify your *Here's what I have* section!

Comment: You still need to extract that content. You can't just assume the CMs and the website will sync without writing PHP to get them to talk

Comment: the CMS **IS** the website

Comment: http://demo.cs-cart.com/ thats the website, its also the CMS. http://demo.cs-cart.com/admin.php?dispatch=auth.login_form&return_url=admin.php thats the admin end where you upload the csv, or add products by hand

Comment: So as long as the domain name is linked to the CMS and the CMS is linked to the hosting server, the products imported into the CMS using the CSV file will appear on each page?

Comment: Why is it that when I go onto a website it will display the following url for a product: www.example.com/12345.php?    I assume this is because they aren't using a CMS and are instead just creating MySQL databases

Comment: 12345 could just be the id used in the db. doses that relate to this particular question - is this 'solved' ?

Comment: Dragon, just got everything sorted by my web host and it turns out you were completely wrong and I was right. Cheers m8

Answer (score 2):

When your CMS is fully installed and connected with your database -which should be the your regular setup- then simply import all your products from your CSV via the [cs.cart import](http://kb.cs-cart.com/product-import):

> 1. In the administration panel, go to `Administration > Import data > Products`.
> 2. Make sure the fields in your CSV file have the same names as the ones listed under the Products section on this page. Also check whether the values of the fields have the correct format. For more information about the correct format read the Imported fields format article.
> 3. In the Import options section, specify the following settings [...]
> 4. Click the Import button.

Comment: I understand that. However, do I not have to use PHP in the products page code on my website to link each product's id with a unique product page?

Comment: No, why? Have you tried out this way? What happens?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote without any comment. Very constructive...

Comment: I didn't downvote you. I'm not even level 15 to downvote you. I was going to try it because someone told me before that the way to get the server to connect to the product page is to use PHP since that is the language to access the server.

Comment: @Dagon: I see, then post another question and we both plead for your answer to be accepted. How 'bout that? :)

Comment: And thanks for removing the downvote btw.

Comment: this turned in to a dog of a "question" so i withdraw.